# Difficulty blocking images on Google Image Search page in chrome extension usign webRequest

Tags: javascript, image, networking, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

[image]

I'm working on a Chrome extension that aims to block images on web pages, and I'm facing an issue with blocking images on the Google Image Search page. Some images are still being displayed. I suspect that Google might be serving some of the images as base64 encoded strings directly in the initial document (?) but I'm unsure about implementation and how to handle this particular use case.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  details => {
    return { cancel: true };
  },
  { urls: ['<all_urls>'], types: ['image'] },
  ['blocking']
);
```

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Cool Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

Comment: The `data:` image doesn't cause any request so webRequest won't see it. You can delete such images in your content script via MutationObserver in `js` or by hiding them via `css`.

Comment: Will MutationObserver/CSS intercept images early enough to prevent any possible flash of content? Also it seems that the same first N images are visible in the same order as they would be even when extension is disabled, so Google doesn't just reorder images that happen to be base64 on top of the page, but rather makes them visible..? Possibly through some additional requests? I would like to also block those.

Comment: Applying CSS at `document_start` coupled with removal of elements in MutationObserver would be flicker-free.

Comment: Thanks, I will try just that! Could modifying the original document response by replacing strings with base64 data also work?

Comment: There's no such API in Chrome other than `chrome.debugger` but it displays a warning while active.